# boolean operator not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that returns a variable is as true . the very first the variable is false and if an events occurs that becomes true.By this true state i want to execute another function.

### My Jquery Codes are

```
var showContents = false,

if(showContents = true){
   $('.element').click(function(){
     close();
   })
}

var show = function(){
   return showContents = true        
}
```

Comment: `showContents` will never be true, because you don't call `show` anywhere

Comment: Actually, `showContents` will *always* be true because you are using a single `=` sign instead of 2. A single one sets the variable's content, two make a comparaison.

Comment: @SterlingArcher i call it into a function i have not mentioned here

Answer (score 8):

`=` is not the 'equals' operator, use `==` or `===` instead.

With `showContents = true` you assign the value `true` to showContents.

Comment: After changing `=` to `==` where appropriate, OP can also simplify `if (showContents == true) ...` to simply `if (showContents) ...`

Comment: Probably best to use `===`: http://www.impressivewebs.com/why-use-triple-equals-javascipt/

Answer (score 2):

The if statement-->

> if(showContents = true){

Is quite wrong. There must be at least two equal signs, and usually three (**==, or ===**).
Also, for an if statement where you check to see if it is true, you can simply put-->

> if(showContents) {

And that is understood to be-->

> if(showContents === true) {

Even so, there is one more issue. For you variable **showContents** you need a semicolon at the end, not a comma.

Answer (score -3):

If you set `showContents` as false, it will never enter inside your if. Moreover,  you have to end the variable `showContents` with an `;`, not with an `,`.

Maybe if you try to explain better what you want to achieve, we can help you better.